# Solving Integral in analytic form takes too long

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

It's my first use of Mathematica. I need to find an integral in analytical form:

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y - h - t)^2 + z^2], {t, -c, c}]
```

where `x,y,h,z` are some real parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use some `Assumptions` to get a fast evaluation. For simplified integrand (`x^2+y^2->x^2, y-h->y`) Mathematica evaluates

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y - t)^2 ], {t, -c, c}, 
Assumptions -> {c > 0, x > 0,Element[{x, y, c}, Reals]} ] ]
(*1/2 Log[-(((c + Sqrt[x^2 + (c - y)^2] - y) (c + y + Sqrt[
  x^2 + (c + y)^2]))/((-c + Sqrt[x^2 + (c - y)^2] + y) (c + y - 
  Sqrt[x^2 + (c + y)^2])))]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

As usually, assuming and avoiding conditions do the job:

```
ClearAll[x, z, y, t, h, c]; 
Integrate[1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y - h - t)^2 + z^2], {t, -c, c}, 
Assumptions -> x > 0 && z > 0 && {h, y} \[Element] Reals && c > 0,GenerateConditions->False]//AbsoluteTiming
(*{45.7708, 1/2 (Log[(c + h - y + Sqrt[
  c^2 + 2 c h + h^2 + x^2 - 2 c y - 2 h y + y^2 + z^2])/Sqrt[
 c^2 + 2 c h + h^2 + x^2 - 2 c y - 2 h y + y^2 + z^2]] - 
Log[(-c - h + y + Sqrt[
  c^2 + 2 c h + h^2 + x^2 - 2 c y - 2 h y + y^2 + z^2])/Sqrt[
 c^2 + 2 c h + h^2 + x^2 - 2 c y - 2 h y + y^2 + z^2]] - 
Log[(-c + h - y + Sqrt[
  c^2 - 2 c h + h^2 + x^2 + 2 c y - 2 h y + y^2 + z^2])/Sqrt[
 c^2 - 2 c h + h^2 + x^2 + 2 c y - 2 h y + y^2 + z^2]] + 
Log[(c - h + y + Sqrt[
  c^2 - 2 c h + h^2 + x^2 + 2 c y - 2 h y + y^2 + z^2])/Sqrt[
 c^2 - 2 c h + h^2 + x^2 + 2 c y - 2 h y + y^2 + z^2]])}*)
```

Comment: Simplify to Log[((c + h - y + Sqrt[(c + h - y)^2 + x^2 + z^2]) (c - (h - y) + 
    Sqrt[(c - (h - y))^2 + x^2 + z^2]))/(x^2 + z^2)]

Comment: @Andreas: `FullSimplify` performs `ArcTanh[(c + h - y)/Sqrt[x^2 + (c + h - y)^2 + z^2]] + 
 ArcTanh[(c - h + y)/Sqrt[x^2 + (c - h + y)^2 + z^2]]`.